# Retired XP machines - which version to install?

Tags: upgrade

I retired several P4 3.4Ghz PCs with 2GB RAM at the office. The hardware is still working but 4-5 years old. Which version of Ubuntu can I use to make these PCs useful. Never used Ubuntu before.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise either [lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net) (running very well on my computer) or [xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org), as these are lightweight. They are both pretty fast, although lubuntu is noticeably faster.

If you want the features, go for Xubuntu, or the speed and similarity to windows, lubuntu. Either of the desktops, installed alongside unity are good, but I advise the while OS as it isn't slow at any point (e.g. logging in when it is just the desktop is painful, as it uses the 14.04 login screen)

Ubuntu with Unity would run on them, however some things may slow it down, and it may be frustrating. XFCE and LXDE would be much faster - even than XP was!

I have a single core intel celeron with 512MB, and it runs faster than XP - it's now use able!

Answer (score 0):

- 700 MHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 512 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 5 GB of hard-drive space (or USB stick, memory card or external drive but see LiveCD for an alternative approach)
- VGA capable of 1024x768 screen resolution
- Either a CD/DVD drive or a USB port for the installer media
- Internet access is helpful

This is a Recommended Minimum System Requirements from a official site ubuntu

If you use a Unity (default Ubuntu grapfic environment) u should have:

- 1000 ΜHz processor (about Intel Celeron or better)
- 1024 MiB RAM (system memory)
- 3D Acceleration Capable Videocard with at least 256 MB